# Does PJSUA supports Android Marshmallow ? Error ./data/simpleua Illegal instruction

Tags: android, c

Does PJSUA supports Android  Marshmallow ?

I am able to cross-compile PJSUA but not able to run on android device.

**I am getting the following error:**

```
root@msm8909:/ # ./data/simpleua                                              
Illegal instruction
```

Please help me to find out correct combination of followings -

```
1: Android version
2: Android-Platform
3: Target-abi
4: Toolchain name
5: Name of library which needs to be copy on android device after cross-compilation, If we need to copy libraries at
    specific path then also please let me know the path.
```

I am following the steps suggested at below link:
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you work at x86 android device?

Comment: yes it 32 bit x86.

Comment: what Target-abi do you use?

Comment: I am not specifying anything in option TARGET_ABI

Comment: processor : 1
model name : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS : 38.40
Features : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part : 0xc07
CPU revision : 5

Hardware : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc MSM8909
Revision : 0000
Serial  : 0000000000000000
Processor : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)

Comment: Below is binary information:
file pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi 
pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped